# How do I remove a CLOSE_WAIT socket connection

Tags: linux, sockets

I have written a small program that interacts with a server on a specific port. The program works fine, but:

Once the program terminated unexpectedly, and ever since that socket connection is shown in `CLOSE_WAIT` state. If I try to run a program it hangs and I have to force it close, which accumulates even *more* `CLOSE_WAIT` socket connections.

Is there a way to flush these connections?

Comment: You can't (and shouldn't). CLOSE_WAIT is a state defined by TCP for connections being closed waiting for the counterpart to acknowledge this.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10106/orphaned-connections-in-close-wait-state ... which I won't vote as a duplicate, because it'd wind up closing the question as off-topic.

Comment: @vonbrand No it isn't, it is exactly the opposite. It is the state for a connection which has already been closed by the peer and is waiting for the local application to close its end.

Comment: If you are using Commons HttpClient then http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/using-httpclient-properly-avoid-closewait-tcp-connections/ has a lot of relevant information. From RFC 2616, Section 14: HTTP/1.1 applications that do not support persistent connections MUST include the "close" connection option in every message.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`CLOSE_WAIT` means your program is still running, and hasn't closed the socket (and the kernel is waiting for it to do so). Add `-p` to `netstat` to get the pid, and then kill it more forcefully (with `SIGKILL` if needed). That should get rid of your `CLOSE_WAIT` sockets. You can also use `ps` to find the pid.

`SO_REUSEADDR` is for servers and `TIME_WAIT` sockets, so doesn't apply here.

Comment: well... kiling the process may not be the best if that program open a lot of connection, only a few of those staying in "CLOSE_WAIT" : in that case killing the process may be completely impossible or unappropriate (the program still works and provides services, with those other connections). Just closing the pending connection would be much more appropriate. but indeed it is usually the program itself which is not closing locally the connectino (CLOSE_WAIT means it received 'FIN' from the other end and the program just have to close the connection locally). A bug report may be appropriate

Answer (score 63):

You can forcibly close sockets with `ss` command. The `ss` command is a utility that allows you to dump socket statistics and displays information sockets, including network connections. It is similar to the `netstat` command, but is generally faster and more efficient.

To forcibly close sockets in the CLOSE_WAIT state using the `ss` command, you can use the `--tcp` option to specify that you want to view TCP sockets, and the `state CLOSE-WAIT` option to specify that you only want to view sockets that are in the CLOSE_WAIT state. For example:

```
$ ss --tcp state CLOSE-WAIT
```

This will display a list of all TCP sockets that are in the CLOSE_WAIT state.

To forcibly close these sockets, you can use the `--kill` option. This will send a signal to the socket, causing it to be closed. For example:

```
$ ss --tcp state CLOSE-WAIT --kill
```

You can also use the `--tcp` option to filter the sockets that you want to close based on various criteria. For example, you can use the `dport` option to specify a specific port number, or the `dst` option to specify a specific destination IP address. For example:

```
$ ss --tcp state CLOSE-WAIT '( dport = 22 or dst 1.1.1.1 )' --kill
```

This will forcibly close all TCP sockets in the CLOSE_WAIT state that are connected to port 22 or have a destination IP address of 1.1.1.1.

It is important to note that using the `ss` command to forcibly close sockets can have unintended consequences, as it may disrupt ongoing network connections. It is generally a good idea to use this command with caution, and only when it is necessary to do so.

Comment: That should be the top answer.

Comment: can we apply a filter to kill only a specific port?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Yeah, of course; you may kill (or list if you want) all sockets by their source or destination port like this: `sudo ss --tcp --kill sport = 54576 or dport = :ssh`

Comment: @MustaphaHadid: Thanks. This is a helpful answer but in my case the result of `ss` is `tcp        0      0 1.1.16.1:57212          1.1.16.28:8081          CLOSE_WAIT  -` with no process id and therefore the `--kill` was unsuccessful. And therefore I am unable to free up this port `57212`.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if the CLOSE_WAIT has become abnormal? I suspect that's possible using the connection time stats collected from "ss" command.

Comment: @MustaphaHadid That didn't work for me. I can see the socket in CLOSE_WAIT state by running this command: ```ss --tcp state CLOSE-WAIT``` but when I tried ```sudo ss --tcp state CLOSE-WAIT --kill``` it gave me this error: ```SOCK_DESTROY answers: Invalid argument```

Comment: @MohammadFaisal This answer explains your `CLOSE_WAIT  -` state: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355636/close-wait-tcp-states-despite-closed-file-descriptors/77420709#77420709

Answer (score 45):

As described by [Crist Clark](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/SunManagers/2006-01/msg00367.html).

> CLOSE_WAIT means that the local end of the connection has received a
>   FIN from the other end, but the OS is waiting for the program at the
>   local end to actually close its connection.
>
> The problem is your program running on the local machine is not
>   closing the socket. It is not a TCP tuning issue. A connection can
>   (and quite correctly) stay in CLOSE_WAIT forever while the program
>   holds the connection open.
>
> Once the local program closes the socket, the OS can send the FIN to
>   the remote end which transitions you to LAST_ACK while you wait for
>   the ACK of the FIN. Once that is received, the connection is finished
>   and drops from the connection table (if your end is in CLOSE_WAIT you
>   do *not* end up in the TIME_WAIT state).

Comment: how to close the socket??

Comment: You close the handle you have to the socket you opened.  Use `close()` or `closesocket()`, depending on which platform you are using.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I suppose the real question is how to wire-it-up in situations where it doesn't automatically happen. Why would a socket not be closed? It couldn't be waiting for incoming data (because of the FIN it would be canceled). Is it a failure to respond to the error condition of such a read operation?

Answer (score 10):

Even though too many CLOSE_WAIT connections mean that there is something wrong with your code in the first place, there is an option, although it is not accepted as good practice.

You might want to check out: https://github.com/rghose/kill-close-wait-connections

What this script does is send out the ACK which the connection was waiting for.

This is what worked for me.

Comment: you send act to close-wait socket. with not works .. if works ,why ?

Comment: I am guessing, the OS has already sent the FIN to the remote host. The remote host probably cannot reply with the ACK that the socket is expecting.

Comment: yes, that's right ( from kernel code). but I also doubt about the SEQ of the packet you send, which is "10", does kernel not check it ?

Comment: Probably not. I think I tried with many random numbers, and they seemed to work.

Answer (score 8):

I'm also having the same issue with a very latest Tomcat server (7.0.40). It goes non-responsive once for a couple of days.

To see open connections, you may use:

```
sudo netstat -tonp | grep jsvc | grep --regexp="127.0.0.1:443" --regexp="127.0.0.1:80" | grep CLOSE_WAIT
```

As mentioned in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10106/orphaned-connections-in-close-wait-state), you may use `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time` to view the values. The value seems to be in seconds and defaults to 7200 (i.e. 2 hours).

To change them, you need to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

```
Open/create `/etc/sysctl.conf`
Add `net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 120` and save the file
Invoke `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`
Verify using `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time`
```

Comment: the answer is confusing. you said the non-responsive states has gone for several days.. but then you also try to set the keep alive time to only 120 seconds. even with the default value (7200 sec), it shouldn't last for several days, right?

Answer (score 3):

It should be mentioned that the `Socket` instance in both client and the server end needs to explicitly invoke `close()`. If only one of the ends invokes `close()` then too, the socket will remain in CLOSE_WAIT state.

Comment: CLOSE_WAIT should only happen if the server didn't invoke close(), if the client also didn't invoke close() then it remains as established. The "confusing" part is that the connection might also go to CLOSE_WAIT even if the server didn't yet invoke accept() on the socket and the client already close()

Comment: clarifying myself; CLOSE_WAIT can't happen unless the server didn't call close(), and it also implies that the client called close() AND it didn't have the socket with linger enabled (which causes an RST to be sent instead of a FIN)

Answer (score 2):

It is also worth noting that if your program spawns a new process, that process may inherit all your opened handles. Even after your own program closs, those inherited handles can still be alive via the orphaned child process. And they don't necessarily show up quite the same in netstat. But all the same, the socket will hang around in CLOSE_WAIT while this child process is alive.

I had a case where I was running ADB. ADB itself spawns a server process if its not already running. This inherited all my handles initially, but did not show up as owning any of them when I was investigating (the same was true for both macOS and Windows - not sure about Linux).