# TCP socket server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Prot Rec Sen Local Address        Foreign Address     State       PID/PXX
tcp  1   0   192.169.3.120:64007  192.169.3.104:40968 CLOSE_WAIT  -               
tcp  7   0   192.169.3.120:64007  192.169.3.104:44637 CLOSE_WAIT  -               
tcp  17  0   192.169.3.120:64007  192.169.3.104:39950 CLOSE_WAIT  -               
tcp  7   0   192.169.3.120:64007  192.169.3.104:34229 CLOSE_WAIT  -
```

The above response is from `sudo netstat -p`.

I have a application sample server which has clients connected. then i stopped the application and started it again it says errror in binding as i didnt use SO_REUSEADDR. i saw that there are few clinet connection in close_wait. i saw that that we need to close the processid of that particular socket. but netstat -p gives blank process id. so how to kill this process as well as is there any way to kill all sockets (exclusively all) using c apis.

Comment: why do you need to kill them explicitly ? they are in timeout mode and will be removed from system soon

Comment: "*... gives blank process id. so how to kill this process id*" you cannot as there are no processes, which is obvious from the empty PID field.

Comment: Possibly of interest:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912370/how-do-i-remove-a-close-wait-socket-connection

Comment: @mangusta CLOSE_WAIT is not a timeout mode. What are you talking about?

Comment: by the way, would be it possible to look at the server code? and the client code?  It's very difficult to conjeture what can be happening there without some code.  And also, are you completely sure you have done the right `netstat` command?  See my answer below.

Comment: @EJP i'm just used to the fact that the socket in `close_wait` state is going to get removed after some time elapsed. you're right, "timeout" is not a proper word in this situation : ))

Comment: @mangusta But it isn't 'going to get removed after some time elapsed'. It will transition to the next state when the local application closes the socket, and not before. There is no timeout associated with this state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CLOSE_WAIT` state indicates some remote client has sent a `FIN` segment to indicate it is not going to send more data, and an `ACK` has been sent to acknowledge, but the application process has not yet `close(2)`d the socket and the kernel is waiting for the local side to be closed.  There must be a local process somewhere having that socket open, as the state is just waiting for a local close.

There are some more states that don't show processes (as there aren't) on sockets managed by the kernel.  But `CLOSE_WAIT` indicates a local process has received a close from the remote side but has not done a close itself yet.  As one of the tasks the kernel does on behalf of a process is to close all its descriptors, if a process has `exit(2)`ed, the close must have been signaled to the socket, moving the state `CLOSE_WAIT` to the `LAST_ACK` (normally not seen)

Answer (score 0):

> I saw that that we need to close the processid of that particular socket

I can't imagine where you saw that, but when a port is in CLOSE_WAIT state it indicates that the application needs to close the *socket*. You have a socket leak.