# Netty socket generate Close_wait status

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tcp, netty

My application java, is running in server, openning port and made connection with devices by socket. Everythings went run till a certain point, lot of connection stay in CLOSE_WAIT, even if my application finish the process on the packet I receive.

What I remark is that CPU began to use double ressource, open file are increasing, and number of CLOSE_WAIT status are increasing also.

In the wireshark, the packet sended which leave a CLOSE_WAIT status, we see that server didn't send FIN to the client.

PS: I'm on ubuntu 14.04 trusty server, I'm using Netty 3.10.1

Here is the code where I Made Pipeline :

```
@Override
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
    if (resetDelay != null) {
        pipeline.addLast("idleHandler", new IdleStateHandler(GlobalTimer.getTimer(), resetDelay, 0, 0));
    }
    pipeline.addLast("openHandler", new OpenChannelHandler(server));
    if (loggerEnabled) {
        pipeline.addLast("logger", new StandardLoggingHandler());
    }
    addSpecificHandlers(pipeline);
    if (filterHandler != null) {
        pipeline.addLast("filter", filterHandler);
    }
    if (reinitializeHandler != null) {
        pipeline.addLast("reinitialize", reinitializeHandler);
    }
    if (refineHandler != null) {
        pipeline.addLast("refine", refineHandler);
    }
    if (noFilterHandler != null) {
        pipeline.addLast("nofilter", noFilterHandler);
    }
    if (specificFilterHandler != null) {
        pipeline.addLast("specificfilter", specificFilterHandler);
    }
    if (reverseGeocoder != null) {
        pipeline.addLast("geocoder", new ReverseGeocoderHandler(reverseGeocoder, processInvalidPositions));
    }
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new TrackerEventHandler(dataManager));
    return pipeline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CLOSE_WAIT means your program is still running, and hasn't closed the socket (and the kernel is waiting for it to do so). Add -p to netstat to get the pid, and then kill it more forcefully (with SIGKILL if needed). That should get rid of your CLOSE_WAIT sockets. You can also use ps to find the pid.

SO_REUSEADDR is for servers and TIME_WAIT sockets, so doesn't apply here.

Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912370/how-do-i-remove-a-close-wait-socket-connection) for other responses.

Check your application code to check if you are explicitly calling close on all the sockets created once you are done handling the client session.

Comment: The application are communicating with lot of device, as I said every thing went correctly till a certain point, which mean that connection is closed by my app. Also I cannot do a kill because my app is communicating with other device that server are closing connection with them correctly.

Comment: Can you share snippets of your code which is responsible for client handling?

Comment: We don't have client code, because it is handled by a device (GPS) that have a program made by our provider. But we know that problem come from our server who SOMETIMES didn't close the connection (by Netty)

Comment: @EspritBat can you add your code where you build the netty pipeline?

Comment: @EspritBat As the others have already pointed out, there seems to be a way in your program (for example an exception) where the channel does not get closed.

Comment: @EJP : I override tree function that close connection `channelIdle(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, IdleStateEvent e)` & `exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e)` & `channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e)` when an IOException is made, connection are closed. @Moh-Aw : In the case I'm talking about, all the pipeline is working well, then when I finish correctly the last step `TrackerEventHandler`, then the connection are not closed. so there is no exception in my part, and if netty generate one, then `exceptionCaught` handle it.

Comment: I don't think you can know this way that the client has closed the connection. Essentially if will need to find out a way to read/write from the socket at regular intervals. When you do that and if the client socket is not available, you will get TCP status 0 or connection is reset by peer.

Comment: I know that client send close from wireshark, and I know that server don't. for the reste of your comment I'm afraid that I don't get it. excuse my low knowledge.

Comment: Even though TCP/IP is "connection oriented" protocol, normally no data is sent over an idle connection. You can have a socket open for a year without a single bit sent over it by the IP stack. In order to notice that a connection is lost, you have to send some data on the application level.(*) Try with an example to implement some kind of application level keepalive mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is leaking sockets by failing to close them. So close them. All of them. In finally blocks. When you read end of stream or get any `IOException` operatng on the socket.