# Open file descriptors of closed sockets in tomcat not cleaned up

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tomcat, file-descriptor

We're running an spring boot (2.3.0) application on a tomcat server (9.0.24) and every so often we get an Too many open files exception, and the application stops working.

I checked the limits of the tomcat instance:

```
Max open files            4096                 4096                 files
```

Running lsof for the process returns a long list of sock files all looking like this:

```
java    17063 tomcat 4085u     sock                0,9       0t0  113306 protocol: TCP
```

```
root@popdb-dev:~# lsof -p 17063 | grep sock | wc -l
4003
```

However when I run ss to see what the sockets do I get a whole lot of closed sockets:

```
root@popdb-dev:~# ss -s
Total: 4384 (kernel 4485)
TCP:   4124 (estab 87, closed 4015, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 0/0), ports 0

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         4485      -         -
RAW       1         0         1
UDP       10        6         4
TCP       109       54        55
INET      120       60        60
FRAG      0         0         0
```

As you can see most of the sockets are already closed. I searched stackoverflow and google but couldn't find any reason why the closed sockets are not cleaned up.
When I stop or restart tomcat the closed sessions are cleaned up.

What can we do so the sockets are cleaned up and our application doesn't stop working?

Comment: Limits can be increased.  But check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912370/how-do-i-remove-a-close-wait-socket-connection.  OS parameters can be tuned to flush these connections faster.

Comment: That seems to be about sockets with status CLOSE_WAIT. If I run ss -4 state CLOSE_WAIT and ss -6 state CLOSE_WAIT I only get 1 connection. so the rest of the closed connections don't show up. Not even when I run ss -4 state all.

Comment: Any one found idea to clear the sockets?