# Tomcat embedded websocket client does not close socket

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I am using Spring Boot + embedded Tomcat to create a websocket client to connect to a server. It works fine except when I close the session; the client socket remains stuck in CLOSE-WAIT state until the application terminates. I was able to reproduce the issue using Tomcat directly to rule Spring out as follows:

Run a server with [websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat) and the following code to connect:

**EDIT:** looks like if I use Spring/Tomcat itself to run the server instead of websocat, it works as expected...

```
WsWebSocketContainer container = new WsWebSocketContainer();
Session session = container.connectToServer(
        MyEndpoint.class, // Just an Endpoint dumb implementation with @ClientEndpoint
        URI.create("ws://localhost:6000"));
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Tomcat", true);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    session.close(new CloseReason(CLOSED_ABNORMALLY, "Closed"));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Then use `ss -tapn "dport = :6000 or sport = :6000"` to verify the sockets. While the client is up, it shows both sockets established:

```
State   Recv-Q  Send-Q        Local Address:Port            Peer Address:Port   Process
LISTEN  0       1024                0.0.0.0:6000                 0.0.0.0:*       users:(("websocat",pid=4128887,fd=6))
ESTAB   0       0                 127.0.0.1:6000               127.0.0.1:47668   users:(("websocat",pid=4128887,fd=7))
ESTAB   0       0        [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:47668     [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:6000    users:(("java",pid=218101,fd=130))
```

After the client closes (theoretically), the server socket goes to FIN-WAIT-2 and eventually releases, but the client socket remains in CLOSE-WAIT until the application terminates:

```
State      Recv-Q  Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port  Process
LISTEN     0       1024                0.0.0.0:6000               0.0.0.0:*      users:(("websocat",pid=4128887,fd=6))
FIN-WAIT-2 0       0                 127.0.0.1:6000             127.0.0.1:47668
CLOSE-WAIT 0       0        [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:47668   [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:6000   users:(("java",pid=218101,fd=130))
```

I have compared with a similar test code using Undertow (not sure this is the "right way" to use it, but it works):

```
WebSocketChannel channel = connectionBuilder(
        XnioWorker.getContextManager().get(),
        new DefaultByteBufferPool(true, 1024),
        URI.create("ws://localhost:6000")).connect().get();
channel.send(TEXT).writeFinal(wrap("Undertow".getBytes()));
Thread.sleep(5000);
channel.setCloseCode(1006);
channel.setCloseReason("Closing");
channel.send(CLOSE).writeFinal(allocate(0));
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

The sockets are closed immediately as expected. I also compared packets sent using tshark:

```
### TOMCAT

    1 0.000000000    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 76 46232 → 6000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65495 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM TSval=1896610021 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2 0.000018691    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 76 6000 → 46232 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65483 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM TSval=1896610021 TSecr=1896610021 WS=128
    3 0.000033368    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 46232 → 6000 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1896610021 TSecr=1896610021
    4 0.004293001    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 221 46232 → 6000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=153 TSval=1896610025 TSecr=1896610021 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    5 0.004319306    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 6000 → 46232 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=154 Win=65408 Len=0 TSval=1896610025 TSecr=1896610025
    6 0.004471741    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    X11 197 Event: <Unknown eventcode 72>, GraphicsExpose, <Unknown eventcode 83>, <Unknown eventcode 58>
    7 0.004486418    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 46232 → 6000 [ACK] Seq=154 Ack=130 Win=65408 Len=0 TSval=1896610025 TSecr=1896610025
    8 0.085399166    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 76 46232 → 6000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=154 Ack=130 Win=65536 Len=8 TSval=1896610106 TSecr=1896610025 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    9 0.128698847    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 6000 → 46232 [ACK] Seq=130 Ack=162 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1896610150 TSecr=1896610106
   10 5.092274818    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 76 46232 → 6000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=162 Ack=130 Win=65536 Len=8 TSval=1896615113 TSecr=1896610150 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   11 5.092298670    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 6000 → 46232 [ACK] Seq=130 Ack=170 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1896615113 TSecr=1896615113
   12 5.092432044    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 6000 → 46232 [FIN, ACK] Seq=130 Ack=170 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1896615113 TSecr=1896615113
   13 5.136818874    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 46232 → 6000 [ACK] Seq=170 Ack=131 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1896615158 TSecr=1896615113
   14 10.417277036    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 46232 → 6000 [FIN, ACK] Seq=170 Ack=131 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1896620438 TSecr=1896615113
   15 10.417302273    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 6000 → 46232 [ACK] Seq=131 Ack=171 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1896620438 TSecr=1896620438

### UNDERTOW

    1 0.000000000    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 76 43438 → 6000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65495 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM TSval=1898801148 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2 0.000021707    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 76 6000 → 43438 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65483 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM TSval=1898801148 TSecr=1898801148 WS=128
    3 0.000037534    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 43438 → 6000 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1898801148 TSecr=1898801148
    4 0.004126341    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 221 43438 → 6000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=153 TSval=1898801152 TSecr=1898801148 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    5 0.004144865    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 6000 → 43438 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=154 Win=65408 Len=0 TSval=1898801152 TSecr=1898801152
    6 0.004286902    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    X11 197 Event: <Unknown eventcode 72>, GraphicsExpose, <Unknown eventcode 51>, <Unknown eventcode 58>
    7 0.004296331    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 43438 → 6000 [ACK] Seq=154 Ack=130 Win=65408 Len=0 TSval=1898801152 TSecr=1898801152
    8 0.025453564    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 82 43438 → 6000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=154 Ack=130 Win=65536 Len=14 TSval=1898801174 TSecr=1898801152 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    9 0.069436675    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 6000 → 43438 [ACK] Seq=130 Ack=168 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1898801218 TSecr=1898801174
   10 5.025353562    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 74 43438 → 6000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=168 Ack=130 Win=65536 Len=6 TSval=1898806173 TSecr=1898801218 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   11 5.025372332    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 6000 → 43438 [ACK] Seq=130 Ack=174 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1898806173 TSecr=1898806173
   12 5.025674619    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 6000 → 43438 [FIN, ACK] Seq=130 Ack=174 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1898806174 TSecr=1898806173
   13 5.026477641    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 43438 → 6000 [FIN, ACK] Seq=174 Ack=131 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1898806175 TSecr=1898806174
   14 5.026491725    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 6000 → 43438 [ACK] Seq=131 Ack=175 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=1898806175 TSecr=1898806175
```

It appears that both sends the close frame as expected, the server sends a FIN and closes, but Tomcat will just ACK and sit on it while Undertow will FIN back and close.

It is a basic behavior but I couldn't get it to work. What am I missing?

Additional info:

- Java 19
- tomcat-embed-websocket version 10.1.18 (also tried 11.0.0-M9 but same thing)
- As mentioned, I'm not using Tomcat directly, but via Spring. But I was able to reproduce the issue without Spring to rule it out.

Comment: So it’s a bug in Websocat.

Comment: Even if it is, the client should not leave sockets hanging like that.

Comment: Curious @Hossomi if you can force close them via `ss` as shown here -https://stackoverflow.com/a/61139251/33204.

Comment: Definitely can, but was looking for a way to prevent that instead of applying brute force.